# how to bind selenium javadoc to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried adding this path to `http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/`

```
project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Selenium-java-2.42.2-srcs.jar
                                                   Selenium-java-2.42.2.jar
```

added javadoc location `http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/` 
But still not working ... 
Does someone know why ?

Comment: Will this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106179/how-to-solve-this-element-has-no-attached-source-and-the-javadoc-could-not-be-f

Comment: Works for me; something else must be going on. Is there a network problem? You know this will not download the docs, but retrieve them over the network each time.

Comment: Doesnt seems to look like Selenium tag related question

Answer (score 7):

**Navigate To:** 
project properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Selenium-java-2.42.2.jar

Select **Selenium-java-2.xx.x.jar** & **Expand** it. 
You will see **Javadoc location option**.
**Select** it and click on **Edit** button.
On next window add **http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/**
link in **javadoc location path** textbox and 
click on **Ok** button.

For more details [Click Here](http://avinashpandeblogsonseleniumautomation.blogspot.in/2016/03/how-to-bind-selenium-javadoc-to-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 1):

project properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => **selenium-*api*-4.2.1.jar**
and add the javadoc link