# Eclipse does not show Javadoc of OpenJDK 12

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I installed OpenJDK 12 including the Javadoc and set the Javadoc URL in Eclipse to `file:/usr/share/doc/java-openjdk/api/` which Eclipse validates. However when I for example press F2 over the String class, I get the message `Note: This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.`.

Could this be due to the modularity of the recent Java versions where java.lang.String resides under java.base, maybe Eclipse did not account for the new file paths? How can I fix this?

**Versions**

I use the newest versions available on Arch Linux at this time of both Java and Eclipse. The exact pacman package versions are:

```
extra/jdk-openjdk 12.0.1.u12-1 
extra/jre-openjdk 12.0.1.u12-1
extra/openjdk-doc 12.0.1.u12-1
community/eclipse-common 4.12-1
community/eclipse-java 4.12-1
```

P.S.: As requested, here my configuration. I don't have the Javadoc installed anymore but I show the new settings with source that work and also how I set it in the past with Javadoc that don't work. **The "Invalid URL" warning was not  there at the time as it did still exist! It validated correctly.**

[image]

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Is that the latest?

Comment: @basilbourque: 4.12.1, the newest version.

Comment: Post such details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Comment: The current version [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) appears to be Eclipse IDE 2019-06 R.

Comment: Have you tried manually selecting the source JAR https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106275/1602555?

Comment: @BasilBourque: Eclipse seems to have two version schemes, where 2019-06 and 4.12 are the same.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki: After installing openjdk-src-12.0.1.u12-1 and pointing Eclipse to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-12-openjdk/lib/src.zip` it works! However I still wonder why it doesn't work with the Javadoc.

Comment: @KonradHöffner The Eclipse Java IDE 2019-06 is built of the Eclipse Platform and the Java Development Tools (JDT) 4.12, EGit/JGit 5.4, m2e 1.12, etc. Please show what you have exactly configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: @howlger: Unfortunately I don't have the Javadoc installed anymore as I use the source now so I can't create an accurate screenshot anymore but I will show as it is now.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't validate your Javadoc location when you specify it as a URL. Was it even correct--it's not in the downloaded OpenJDK 12 build I have?

Comment: I used the browse button to select the folder which produced that url. It wasn't included in the open jdk but in its own package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an arch linux user and I had the same problem. I have overcome this problem at the end of the day. I would like to note that if you are downloading jdk packages in linux, you should also download javadoc and source packages. After this, the src.zip folder will be created.

```
sudo pacman -S jdk8-openjdk jdk11-openjdk jdk17-openjdk jdk-openjdk openjdk8-doc  openjdk11-doc openjdk17-doc openjdk21-doc openjdk8-src openjdk11-src openjdk17-src openjdk21-src
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on ubuntu with openjdk-17.
Checked the installed packages and noticed that I only had `openjdk-17-jdk` installed and with `openjdk-17-doc` and `openjdk-17-source` available but not installed. After installing those two fixed the problems with eclipse.